# Jump to CSS definition when editing HTML in VIM

Tags: workflow, vim

For example I am editing `index.html or index.php` in VIM and I have the following code in there:

```
<div id="header">

// some code

</div>
```

When I move my cursor to the word `header` I want to jump to the position in my CSS-file where the tag (id/class) is defined. ctags doesnt work with this. Thx for advise!

Comment: See this blog for [ctags + css](http://scie.nti.st/2006/12/22/how-to-add-css-support-to-ctags) (not tested).

Comment: @romainl Good answer, ought to make it one. :)

Comment: OK. But I have no idea if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to patch ctags so that it supports CSS. [This guy explains how](http://scie.nti.st/2006/12/22/how-to-add-css-support-to-ctags) but I have no idea if it works or not. I'll probably give this solution a try very soon as I think this feature would kick ass.

Also, I should add that I didn't pull this old blog post from my magic bookmarks hat. It was one of the first results of a very simple Google query, did you look around before asking here? And, if you did, what did you found/try?

See also [there](http://book.abe.free.fr/blog/public/ctags) and [there](http://designtomarkup.com/vim/taglist-ctags-css-patch).

***edit***

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12924218/546861) doesn't require patching/compiling and works very well.

Comment: I've used http://designtomarkup.com/vim/taglist-ctags-css-patch, and it worked fine (with the precompiled Windows binary).

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that. However, I hope that a special parser is both faster and more robust than the regexp alternative you're mentioning. (E.g., I don't see the regexp handling multiple comma-separated definitions on the same line.)

Comment: Those regexp patterns are used by ctags so I'd expect this solution to work reasonably fast. About the multiple comma-separated definitions: I *never* do that, maybe I should take a look at it.