# Vim plugin that allows to follow css class from a slim file to a SASS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, ctags, slim-lang, exuberant-ctags

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find a ctag language definition for `slim` (for `Ruby on Rails`).

It would be great if someone can point me in the right direction :-)

Comment: See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12833189/546861).

Comment: Haha! Thanks! :-) I see your answers about VIM all over the place! I had forgotten to change the title of this question before posting; my bad =) I was looking for a ctag language definition for slim and it would be great if I could get it to jump to SASS. I could probably modify your `JumpToCSS()` if no plugin exists :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `.less` section of my `~/.ctags` file:

```
--langdef=less
--langmap=less:.less
--regex-less=/^[ \t&]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-less=/^[ \t&]*\.([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*(([A-Za-z0-9_-]+[ \t\n,]+)+)\{/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,media,medias/
--regex-less=/^[ \t]*(@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+):/\1/v,variable,variables/
```

the `.scss` section:

```
--langdef=scss
--langmap=scss:.scss
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@mixin ([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/m,mixin,mixins/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*\$([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/v,variable,variables/
--regex-scss=/^([A-Za-z0-9_-]*)*(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\1/c,class,classes/
--regex-scss=/^(.*)*\#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+) *[,{]/\2/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*#([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-scss=/(^([A-Za-z0-9_-])*([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^([^\/\/])*)[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^(.*, *)([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\3/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/(^[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)) *[,|\{]/\1/t,tag,tags/
--regex-scss=/^[ \t]*@media\s+([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/\1/d,media,media/
```

and the `.html` section:

```
--regex-html=/id="([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"/\1/i,id,ids/
--regex-html=/class="([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)"/\1/c,class,classes/
```

You will probably get something workable if you start with these.

Comment: Thanks! This should get me started :-)